# Adding Firebase UI to android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I need to get a hands-on on firebase list and recycler adapters. I've added the required firebase ui dependency but for reasons unknown to me, I keep getting this error:

```
 Failed to resolve: com.firebase:firebase-ui:0.3.1
```

I've throttled the dependency version back and forth(0.1.0,0.3.1, 0.4.0) and neither of them works for me. I could use some help here.

Comment: this is the latest firebase UI compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.0' you can as well check the project repo on github https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: Thanks..I have solved this issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

What is the google play services version of yours.
if 9.8.0, use below for compatibility reasons

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.0'
```

https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-android#using-the-library-in-your-android-app

Comment: @ugoboz. My play services version is 9.8.0. and I have added the 1.0.0 dependency. It shows: Error:Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.0.0. What next?

Comment: @ugoboz .Pls don't bother. I figured a way to get past that problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yh..it sorta helped even though I googled it before seeing your response just now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In the app's build.gradle I add to the firebase core library to the dependencies :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
```

Then depending which modules of firebase I want to use in addition, I add those in too, such as:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

To use FirebaseUI, you need to add some dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'

// Required only if Facebook login support is required
implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0')

// Required only if Twitter login support is required
implementation("com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1@aar") { transitive = true }
```

Here is more information: [FirebaseUI-android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui)